# MySQLi PHP Warning

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql, database, joomla-3.6

I am getting the following errors (in this order) thousands of times in my error log:

```
[08-Jun-2016 13:11:05 America/Detroit] PHP Warning:  mysqli::stat(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in {...}/libraries/joomla/database/driver/mysqli.php on line 219
[08-Jun-2016 13:11:05 America/Detroit] PHP Warning:  mysqli_close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in {...}/libraries/joomla/database/driver/mysqli.php on line 226
```

Here is the function within the **mysqli.php** file that has lines 219 [`if ($this...`] and 226 [`mysqli_close($this...`]:

```
/**
 * Disconnects the database.
 *
 * @return  void
 *
 * @since   12.1
 */
public function disconnect()
{
    // Close the connection.
    if ($this->connection instanceof mysqli && $this->connection->stat() !== false)
    {
        foreach ($this->disconnectHandlers as $h)
        {
            call_user_func_array($h, array( &$this));
        }

        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }

    $this->connection = null;
}
```

I have another Joomla! 3.6.2 site on this server with only a few occurrences of this error one day, so I assume it is a local issue. However, the other site is an exact mirror with a slightly modified theme and fewer extensions, so I am a little confused as to how to proceed.

I did have a few other reference warnings in my theme files. Those have been resolved, but the above warnings continue. I, also, upgraded from PHP 5.4 -> 5.5, but there is no change.

---

**Note 1:**

The errors always come in pairs on lines 219 & 226 of `mysqli.php`. And, they always occur more than 1 pair at a time. Example: On 26-Aug-2016 11:10:25 there were *10 pairs* of these errors (20 lines total) *at the exact same second*.

---

**Note 2:**

I ran a Database "Fix", but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: This may be related to: https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/9511

Comment: [@Lodder](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/168/lodder), I am running MySQL 5.6

Comment: [@NeilRobertson](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/120/neil-robertson), I don't have those same issues. However, I did run the Database "Fix" button as suggested, but with no success.

Comment: I continue to get 100's of these errors, daily. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sometimes that can be from a resources issue.  Can you post your php.ini for memory, execution time, etc?

Comment: @YellowWebMonkey
memory_limit 256M;
max_execution_time 180

Comment: Given that running the Akeeba database-only backup will trigger the error, I would post on the Akeeba support.  Those guys are geniuses.  If anyone can figure it out, it would be them.

Comment: @YellowWebMonkey, the error when backing up the database in Akeeba is a "software" error ("The archive is corrupt.") and does not trigger any PHP errors in the error_log. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I would assume the difference between the problem site and one that rarely gets it would be either 1) An extension only on problem site or 2) the problem site just gets a lot more traffic so the problem occurs more often.  Can you reconcile between your two sites and let us know which extensions are on the problem site versus the one that rarely gets it?  How does the traffic compare?

Comment: could this help?

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411914/php-error-heppen-warning-mysqliclose-couldnt-fetch-mysqli-error-in-php

Comment: @YellowWebMonkey,

1. It's possible that there is a poorly coded extension that I am using. However, they are too numerous to list. With a little time, I could create a list of extensions not used on the clone site.
2. The problem site gets about 30x more traffic than the clone site.

Comment: @Anant, I haven't written any code that accesses the database. However, I suppose I could be using an extension that uses a faulty connection to the database.

Comment: Your answers makes me think that it is a shared extension then since cloned site also receives error just in much smaller percentage.  I would clear the error log on cloned site, then go to some of the major pages on that site one at a time and hit refresh several times (might have to submit form if it is a search page,etc), then check log to see if error is generated.  It's a bit of a needle in a haystack, but without having access to anything, it's the best advice I have at the moment.

Comment: @YellowWebMonkey, looking at analytics for the cloned site, on the one day where the error occurred, the traffic was at its lowest (<100 pageviews). :/ 

This does seem like a "needle in a haystack" issue. However, at one point I had to clear the error log because it was 0.5 GB, mostly all this error! So, unless I want to let it ride and keep clear the error log every few weeks, I've got to hunt it down. :(

Comment: I was just suggesting clearing it for a blank slate on clone, then try to recreate the error systematically so you could see what page it was occurring on, then what extension.  It's not the best solution in the slightest, but it's all I got at this point.   Hopefully someone else has some ideas.

Comment: OK, I don't know how, but the clone site produced the same errors twice within an hour 2 days ago. I'm in the process of creating a comparison chart of the extensions for the two sites.

Comment: I was able to fix the Akeeba Backup issue, which was unrelated (just a backup profile setting).

Comment: Have you managed with your problem? I have it the same and no idea what to do. Radek

Comment: @radek: No, I have not. Yesterday, I had **128 PHP warnings** related to *mysqli* [64 stat()/close() pairs] in the `error_log` at 17 times, some just milliseconds apart! :(

Comment: 3 years later this question has deadended and appears abandoned.  More specific details are required for volunteers to offer accurate support.  Until this question is improved, it needs to be put on hold so that the system stops bumping it.

Comment: @mickmackusa what additional info can be provided to get a working solution?

Comment: Wow, @Michael are you still seeking a solution for this? Are you still able to replicate this error? YellowWebMonkey asked for you to keep stripping away extensions one-by-one until the issue disappeared -- then tell us which extension was to blame ...then you/we can investigate the trouble within that specific extension. The possible causes need to be narrowed down so that volunteers can confidently provide an answer (as opposed to firing blind guesses). I'm very happy to reopen this page if you can provide new relevant clues for this cold case.

Comment: My suspicion is that an extension is prematurely `->close()`ing the database connection, or perhaps a class method cannot access the connection due to a namespacing issue or something else ...these are "blind guesses" that I would rather not post as an answer.

Comment: I had 300 of these warnings yesterday alone. Only, now they are on lines 213 and 220 of the same file. They are almost always 10 pairs at the exact second.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JCH Optimize plugin, you might see these errors. Try to disable the plugin.

Comment: I am running JCH on this site and a mirror site. The mirror site does not produce these errors (aside from 1 time 2 weeks ago).

Comment: You cannot predict caching from one site to other. Just give it a try to see if it is the issue. you can always enable it again.

Comment: I am waiting for the next occurrence of the error, then I will be testing without JCH for a few hours to see if the error occurs, again.

Comment: After disabling JCH and clearing the cache, the errors still occur at least once per hour.

Answer (score 0):

Have you corrected the database in extensions menu? After upgraded your Joomla?

Extensions -> Database -> Fix button

Comment: The page shows... "Notice: Database table structure is up to date."

Comment: I tried to run a "Fix", but nothing changed:



    Database schema version (in #__schemas): 3.6.0-2016-06-05.
    Update version (in #__extensions): 3.6.2.
    Database driver: mysqli.
    97 database changes were checked successfully.
    156 database changes did not alter table structure and were skipped.